# Update frequency variable using Scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

My problem is fairly simple: I want to set a frequency and then click a button to plot the corresponding sine function. Unfortunately, the program does not update the frequency value. As the scale begins at zero, I understand that the frequency is always zero. How do I make the program update the frequency?

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Top = Tk()

value = float()
Label(textvariable=value).pack()
Scale(from_=0, to_=10, variable=value).pack()

def plot():
    freq = value
    t = np.arange(0,20,0.01)
    f = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
    plt.plot(t,f,'r-')
    plt.show()


Button(text='Plot', command=plot).pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `variable` option of a `Scale` (and the `textvariable` option of a `Label`) takes an `IntVar`, a `DoubleVar` or a `StringVar`, not just any python variable. The difference between them is the type of the value returned (respectively int, float or str). They have a `get` method to retrieve the value and a `set` method to change it.

So, the following changes will fix your code:

`value = float()` -> `value = DoubleVar(Top)`

`freq = value` -> `freq = value.get()`